# Why would $\arctan(\tan(\frac{4\pi}{3}))$ not be $\frac{4\pi}{3}$?

Tags: trigonometry

> Why would $\arctan(\tan(\frac{4\pi}{3}))$ not be $\frac{4\pi}{3}$?

I understand somewhat the reasoning for why the answer is $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and assume that it has something to do with reference angles or some sort of property related to the unit circle. What exactly is the reasoning behind why the solution is $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and not $\frac{4\pi}{3}$? Would the $\arctan$ and $\tan$ not cancel out?

Comment: Similarly it is not true in general that $\sqrt{x^2}\neq x$ (indeed $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$) and it is related to the assumed definition for the inverse function.

Comment: $\arctan\left(\tan\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)$ is $\arctan(\sqrt{3})$. The $\arctan$ "can't see" the angle that generated the tangent value $\sqrt{3}$. For all $\arctan$ knows, the angle could've been $\pi/3$, or $4\pi/3$, or $1234567\pi/3$, or any of infinitely-many other possibilities. Ultimately, $\arctan$ *doesn't care*: $\arctan$ is *defined* to give the "principal angle" (between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$) associated with a given tangent value; in the case of the tangent value $\sqrt{3}$, that principal angle is $\pi/3$.

Comment: $\arctan x$ is defined so $x=\tan\arctan x$, but $\arctan\tan x$ must be periodic because $\tan x$ is, so it can't be the identity function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that tangent is not a 1-1 function, so we can't define a full inverse function on it.  Instead, we choose the strip $(-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2)$ to restrict the domain of tangent on.   For that restricted function, we can then invert it to get the function we call arctan.   This means that the range of arctan is the domain of the restricted function,  $(-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2)$.  So arctan only fully cancels tangent if the input is in the $(-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2)$ strip, otherwise it gives the angle shifted by units of $\pi$ until it is inside.